# how to solve the given differential equation....

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to find the general solution of the differential equation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=(\frac{dy}{dx})^2$..
I tried:

$\begin{aligned}\int\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}dx&=\int (\frac{dy}{dx})^2dx\\\frac{dy}{dx}&=\int (\frac{dy}{dx})^2dx\end{aligned}$

How should I deal with this integral or how should I solve the given differential equation to obtain the required general solution.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the solutions to:$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784697/find-the-solutions-to-fracd2ydx2-left-fracdydx-right2)

Answer (score 0):

Let $y'=z$ , $y''=z'$

$z'=z^{2}$

$z=\frac{-1}{a+x}$

$y=\int\frac{-1}{a+x} dx$

$$y=b-\ln(a+x)$$

Comment: but I am not getting how we get :$z=\frac{-1}{a+x}$

Comment: $\frac{dz}{dx}=z^{2}$ , $\int\frac{1}{z^{2}}dz=\int dx$ , $\frac{-1}{z}=x+c$ , $z=\frac{-1}{x+c}$